# GLES20 Texturing - do I glUniform1i(uniformLoc, txtUnit) before or after glActiveTexture() + glBindTexture()?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Let's say I play a video on a `GLSurfaceView` with a custom renderer, and in said renderer I use a fragment shader that takes an extra texture for lookup filtering. Said fragment shader looks as follows:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;

uniform samplerExternalOES u_Texture;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;

varying highp vec2 v_TexCoordinate;

void main()
{
    vec3 texel = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate).rgb;
    texel = vec3(
        texture2D(inputImageTexture2, vec2(texel.r, .16666)).r,
        texture2D(inputImageTexture2, vec2(texel.g, .5)).g,
        texture2D(inputImageTexture2, vec2(texel.b, .83333)).b
    );

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texel, 1.0);
}
```

In the `onDrawFrame()` function, after the `glUseProgram()` call, I have the `onPreDrawFrame()` function that basically binds said texture into the shader's uniform. It currently looks like this:

```
public void onPreDrawFrame()
{
    if (filterSourceTexture2 != -1 && filterInputTextureUniform2 != -1) {
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, filterSourceTexture2);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(filterInputTextureUniform2, 2);
    }
}
```

`filterSourceTexture2` is the texture unit corresponding to the extra texture.

What I'm confused of is that if I put the `glUniform1i()` call before `glActiveTexture()`, it still works fine, but most of the tutorials I've seen put the `glUniform1i()` call like the above code.

So which is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

The 2 make no difference. What you pass through the uniform is which active texture should be used in the fragment shader. Next to that you need to bind the texture id to the actual active texture. So the only order you will see here is that active texture must be called before binding.

Now in most cases you will see the same sequence as already mentioned: active, bind, set uniform. But when it comes to optimizing the code this will change:

Since you might want to decrease the traffic to the GPU you will want to reduce redundant calls to uniforms. A single uniform call will not benefit you much but still... You will initialize the shader and then set all the default uniforms so you will not set them on every draw frame call. In your case that means you will have 2 textures and for the first one this will always be active texture 0 and for the second one always active texture 1. So set the 2 uniforms first and then once you need to bind the new textures simply do that, preferably not in every draw call.

Some other implementations include that you have a custom shader object which remembers what your previous setting was so it will not send the same value to the shader again:

```
if(this.myUniform != newValue) {
    this.myUniform = newValue;
    GLES20.glUniform1i(filterInputTextureUniform2, newValue);
}
```

But the problem is this system may in the end be slower then if you actually just set the uniform again.

So the actual answer to which is recommended: I recommend setting the uniform first in some initialization if possible which means the sequence is not even in the same method. But if they are in the same method I suggest you to set the uniform last due to the readability but that would mean setup both textures first (active plus bind) and then set the 2 uniforms one after the other.

**And just a note about "most tutorials":**

Most of the tutorials you will find are designed to show you how the API works. They are designed for you to be able to easily identified what calls must be made and in which order (if any). This leads to usually having all the code in a single source file which should not be done for real applications. Remember to build your tools as you see fit and separate them into different classes. In the end your "on draw" method should have no more then 50 lines no matter the size of the project or scenes you are drawing.